# Pywikibot get links used in the main text

Tags: python, api, wikipedia, pywikibot

Is it possible to return the only the article hyperlinks used in the content text of a wiki page using Pywikibot? I have tried `iterwikilinks()` but that doesn't return the correct links I am looking for. Is there another method or API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look for:

```
pywikibot.Page.linkedPages()
```